# Let $f$ be an entire function. And assume $f(z)$ is real on $Im(z)=0$ and $Im(z)=\pi$ lines. Show $f$ is $2\pi i$ periodic.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function. And assume $f(z)$ is real on $Im(z)=0$ and $Im(z)=\pi$ lines. Show $f$ is $2\pi i$ periodic.

No clue how to start this problem. I was thinking of maybe equating it to some iteration of $e^z$ but that got me nowhere.

Comment: Do you know [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle)?

Comment: @user10354138 I do know of it.

Comment: Reflect at one line. And reflect at the other

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z)=\overline {f(\overline {z})}$. The $g$ is entire and $g=f$ on the real axis. Hence $g=f$ everywhere by the Identity Theorem. Now use the  second part of the hypothesis to conclude that $f(x-\pi i)=f(x+\pi i)$ for $x$ real.